# how to replace SNAPSHOT version when releasing jar using maven release plugin

Tags: java, maven

I first ran maven locally using:

```
mvn release:prepare -DreleaseVersion=1.1.2 -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -Dresume=false -Dtag=1.1.2 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

but some third party dependencies like :

```
<properties>
  <core.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</core.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>${core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to replace `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` with `1.0.0`,What should I do now?

Comment: change them manually. you are depending on a framework to magically know what release version you want to use? even if that worked, that would be asking for trouble.

Comment: there are five projects,A depends on B,I want to release them at the same time,I released B with 1.1.1,and I must to modify A...Is there a way to automatically modify them in jenkins?

Comment: Before you release the project where you are using the dependency on `com.demo:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` you have to release the `com.demo:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` which will become `com.demo:core:1.0.0`. Then change the version to `1.0.0` and afterwards you can release the project.

Comment: Even if that is possible (which I doubt) it would be a bad idea. If your initial release fails, you are going to check five releases which one failed and why? Also: jenkins is not going to check which releases exist for every artifact, nor will it know which version you want to update to

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, what he wants is all the 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT of the dependencies being done automatically

Comment: Do those five projects belong together? If so create a multi module of it and you have it in one go...

Comment: Our build server runs `versions:use-releases` before running the maven release plugin. This reduces the trouble with forgotten SNAPSHOT dependencies. It does not help with properties, though.

Comment: Shell can modify `pom.xml`,but there is a lot of work,tag...commit...,my idea is to release five projects in turn and modify version properties.